# setfacl rights for docker in fedora for symfony cache

Tags: symfony, docker, fedora

at our company we're using Docker and most of the developers used Ubuntu. I now switched to Fedora and set everything up except for the access rights through `ACL`.

In Ubuntu we did a simple `setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwX -m u:$USER:rwX {folderList}`, however in Fedora26 the group `www-data` does not exist.

Welp, I could simply create the group but this doesn't fix the problem I guess, because it somehow still needs to be "connected" to docker, right?

The problem I'm having is, that the Symfony application can't write into the `cache` folders because It doesn't have rights. This is what we use `setfacl` for, but I have no idea how to fix this in Fedora.

Comment: The web server user might bi different, for Apache can be `apache` instead of `www-data`. Check your user with: `ps aux | grep your_web_server`. Then use: `setfacl -R -m g:apache...`

Comment: Looks like the username for Apache in Fedora is "apache"

Comment: I'm using nginx, but it seemed like I had to use the id of the user/group (33, which is the id of www-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by connecting into my docker machine, making an `cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data` and saw, that the id of this user/group is 33 (the same, the php-fpm child process pools are created) and then simply used

`setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwX -m u:$USER:rwX {folderList}`